# Unable to install ubuntu: "Couldn't get size"

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, uefi, nomodeset

I want to completely get rid of Microsoft (thus Windows), and I really love the Ubuntu operating system and applications.
I had Ubuntu installed before on my computer, and it worked perfectly. For some reason I switched back to Windows, but now I want to completely get rid of Windows, but I can't.
I've installed Ubuntu several times on mine and others' pcs. It has always worked, but now I'm stuck at the very unclear sentence `Couldn't get size`.

This is a screenshot I took when I tried starting the Ubuntu installer using `nomodeset`:
[image]

I've searched on this and other forums, and I've found a couple of solutions, including:

- Using `nomodeset` & `nouveau.modeset=0` (See screenshot)
- Using `no splash`
- Using `CSM` in UEFI setup
- Using `Secure Boot` either enabled or disabled in UEFI (Tried both)
- Using `Safe Graphics` when booting from GRUB
- Using the motherboard graphics instead of GPU by plugging in the HDMI cable directly to the motherboard

Actually, nothing worked... I keep getting `Couldn't get size`. And when I remove `quiet splash` or use `no splash`, I see `Registered PHC Clock`. I know this isn't an error, but it hangs on that one and don't continue booting (even after 30 minutes).

I hope someone has a brilliant idea, which makes my system at least boot into the installer & desktop where I can fix some issues.
Thanks in advance for anyone who wants to help!

Regards, Luuk.

*P.S. I don't think it's caused by the GPU, because it also doesn't work with the motherboard graphics...*

Comment: Can you run Ubuntu in Live Session? Is it possible to use a different USB port (maybe an old USB2.0 instead USB3.0 port). I had similiar issue during installation of Ubuntu from USB on my HP Elitebook 8560p, it was only possible from the older USB2.0 ports)

Comment: I also tried that. Live USB gives the same error, and USB2.0 also didn't make any difference. I don't know what to do anymore... :(

Comment: Is the USB stick working with an other computer? If not, maybe the image is broken.

Comment: Its working on my second (spare) laptop.

Comment: @Mr.Michael.Schulze As I said before, nothing works. And now I can't even start Windows  (My only installed operating system..). Do you have a suggestion? I really need my computer for many things, and I can't use it right now...